# ¿Cómo eliminar un subdirectorio con PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo un sistema que funciona así:

Primero registre el álbum y luego la imagen referente al álbum registrado. Así que el camino se ve así:

fotos/albums/{nombre del álbum creado}/{nombre de la foto que hace referencia al álbum}

El directorio photos/ y el subdirectorio albums/ son fijos, es decir, no se borran. Quiero eliminar el álbum creado y las fotos relacionadas con ellos. Para eso, estoy tratando de la siguiente manera:

```
function public deleteAlbums($id)
{
   $sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM....");
   $nc = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);
   $directorio = "fotos/albums/".$nc->AlbumName;
   $this->deleteDirectory($directorio);
}

 function public deleteDirectory($dir) {
    $archivos = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..'));
    foreach ($archivos as $archivo){
        (is_dir("$dir/$archivo") ? $this->deleteDirectory("$dir/$archivo") : unlink("$dir/$archivo"));
    }
    $antiguo = umask(0);
    return rmdir($dir);
    umask($antiguo);
  }
```

El problema es que cuando hago eso, también borra el subdirectorio albums/ y con eso todos los álbumes creados y no solo el álbum que quiero borrar.

¿Cómo resuelvo esto?

Perdona mi español.

Comment: Gracias por los ajustes HeytalePazguato.

Comment: Dónde define $nc?  Tal vez está vacio?

Comment: Hola Duston. Viene de la base de datos. Ajusté mi publicación para una mejor comprensión.

Comment: ¿Por qué mejor no borrar el directorio completo, a un más bajo nivel, mediante este comando: `shell_exec("rm -rf " . $directorio);` Lo harías desde tu primer bloque de código, sería más simple y más rápido.

Answer (score 1):

Esto podría resolverse de una forma mucho más simple y eficaz a un nivel más bajo, mediante línea de comando ejecutada mediante [**`exec()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

Por ejemplo:

```
function public deleteAlbums($id)
{
   $sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM....");
   $nc = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);
   $directorio = "fotos/albums/".$nc->AlbumName;
   exec("rm -rfv $directorio 2>&1", $output, $code);
   /*Esto es opcional*/
    var_dump($output);
    var_dump($code);
}
```

Esto te borrará todo lo que haya en `$directorio`, sin necesidad de tu segunda función. Al trabajar a un nivel más bajo, este código debería ir más rápido que borrando desde PHP.

El primer `var_dump` mostrará algo como esto (todos los directorios, subdirectorios y archivos borrados). En el ejemplo, `$directorio` es un folder que en su vida se llamó `fordelete`, pero que hoy ya no existe:

```
array(5) 
{ 
    [0]=> string(42) "removed 'fordelete/subfolder/homilias.txt'" 
    [1]=> string(40) "removed directory: 'fordelete/subfolder'" 
    [2]=> string(32) "removed 'fordelete/homilias.txt'" 
    [3]=> string(30) "removed 'fordelete/padres.txt'" 
    [4]=> string(30) "removed directory: 'fordelete'" 
}
```

Y el segundo `var_dump` te mostrará el [código de salida](https://support.microfocus.com/kb/doc.php?id=7021956) `0`, el cual significa que la operación fue exitosa:

```
int(0)
```

Si no te interesa una salida detallada de lo ocurrido (primer `var_dump`), puedes pasar `null` en el primer parámetro y quitar la bandera **`v`** (verbose) en el comando, así como **`2>&1`**. Revisa al respecto lo que dice el Manual de PHP.

### Recomendación

Debes hilar fino en la construcción de tu código, y debes estar seguro de que apuntas al directorio correcto que quieres eliminar, pues la ejecución de este comando podría ser irreversible.